# Mercurial - pull all remote bookmarks without knowing names?

Tags: mercurial

Is there an option in Mercurial that allows me to pull all remote bookmarks without having to know their names in advance?

On the [Mercurial Bookmarks page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks/) it mentions that when I *clone* a repository, I get all the bookmarks.

However, I'm in the situation where I already have the repository, create a few heads, each with a bookmark explaining what they are, and push all (including the bookmarks) to the server.

When Bob pulls my changes he is going to get all the hanging heads I've created and it may be hard to tell which one he is meant to work on.

If he's going to get lots of hanging heads from my changes anyway, I want him to at least get the bookmarks that go with them so it's clearer to him what's going on! (Typically my default branch is my dev branch, which has a 'dev' bookmark and numerous other 'feature' bookmarks - I don't want these as branches as they won't last for long - I want Bob to be able to know straight away which head corresponds to what he wants to work on).

cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hg incoming -B` shows you the remote bookmarks.

In hg 2.3 you should automatically get all remote bookmarks on pull.

> - bookmarks: pull new bookmarks from remote by default

→ http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_2.3_.282012-08-01.29

Comment: Hmm, I'm on 2.0.2, and `hg incoming -B` only shows you changes on bookmarks you already have, not the list of remote bookmarks. I guess I just have to wait til hg 2.3 and in the meantime just have to remember the names of the bookmarks myself...

Comment: seems so… you might be able to write a small extension which gets the bookmark names, though. Maybe a good start: http://selenic.com/hg/file/2.0.2/mercurial/bookmarks.py#l151

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, you can add the mercurial PPA:
`apt-add-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases`