# How to bring latest changes in a mercurial feature branch (workflow)?

Tags: mercurial

Given a branch called 'main'. As a developer wanting to work on a new feature, I create 'f1' and do several commits, pushing regularly to our central repo. While working on the feature, I need to get the changes form 'main' in my branch.

I know I can `hg merge main` to get the changes in 'f1'. But when I later integrate in 'main' then the history will be full of references to that temporary branch. Are there ways to make my branch work less visible after the fact?

Comment: let me rephrase before closing...

Comment: done, let me know if it is still not clear

Comment: There are no. In mercurial named branches are persistent

Comment: Named branches are permanent. You could use unnamed heads or bookmarks (which are temporary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why do you worry about that the main branch would contain the history of the f1 branch after merging the latter to the former, if the f1 branch is already in the central repo??? The f1 branch is not temporary/disposable/invisible any more once it's pushed into the central repo, it's **very** visible to everyone who can access the central repo.

The answer to your question is: No way unless f1 is a by-cloning branch. All suggestions of using bookmark and/or anonymous branch are false.

Answer (score 1):

To make branch less visible in history you should use [bookmarks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks/). Let's see both cases, with a named branch or with a bookmark.

With new branch named 'f1' from 'main':

```
$ hg update main
$ hg branch f1
...
$ hg glog --template "{rev} {branch} {bookmarks} {desc}\n"

@  5 main  Hacking main.
|
| o  4 f1  Hacking f1.
| |
| o  3 f1  Hacking f1.
|/
o  2 main  Hacking main.
|
o  1 main  Hacking main.
|
o  0 default
```

With new bookmark named 'f1' from 'main':

```
$ hg update main
$ hg bookmark f1
...
$ hg glog --template "{rev} {branch} {bookmarks} {desc}\n"

@  5 main  Hacking main.
|
| o  4 main f1 Hacking f1.
| |
| o  3 main  Hacking f1.
|/
o  2 main  Hacking main.
|
o  1 main  Hacking main.
|
o  0 default
```

In the bookmark case the 'f1' feature can be removed from history with `hg bookmarks --delete f1` (from Mercurial 2.3 new bookmarks are pulled by default [WhatsNew](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_2.3_.282012-08-01.29)) and there are two paths in the 'main' branch.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work very well if he wants to push regularly to his central repo.  The push will fail because of the extra head and if you override this, other developers may get your head instead of the head that they should have got when they pull and update.

Comment: Yes. May be can apply some from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661904/mercurial-pull-all-remote-bookmarks-without-knowing-names.

Comment: @SteveKaye : that is indeed why I don't want to use bookmarks because if I push after I've merged 'main' then that becomes the tip for 'main' although other devs need the other 'main' head.